# Can we check if Kubernetes cluster have enough of resources before asking for new deployment On-Prem cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Do we have some Api in Kubernetes to know if we have enough resources to run deployment of pods before sending the request on prem envirenment?

the reason I need it is because I want to run a pod from another pod and I want to make sure I have enough of resources.

Comment: The resources (cpu, memory)can be defined at deployment level with minimum, maximum resources required for a container.  Based on these values k8s will determine whether required resources are available on the node before scheduling.  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/

Answer (score 1):

To get information about CPU(cores), CPU%, memory, and memory% usage of your nodes, you can run `kubectl top nodes` command.

For example:

```
1 kubectl top node --use-protocol-buffers
2 NAME           CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
3 example-node   500m         50%    573Mi           20%
```

- CPU(cores) - 500m means 500 millicpu. 1000m is equal to 1 CPU, hence 500m means 50% of 1 CPU.
- CPU% - Total CPU usage percentage of that node.
- Memory - Memory being used by that node.
- Memory% - Total memory usage percentage of that node.